# Position of "neither" in the following sentence

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Is this variation of **neither** acceptable?

> He could neither clearly identify the man who attacked him nor he could name the weapon with which he was attacked.

To my ears, this sentence sounds eccentric due to wrong position of *neither*. I think *He could neither* should be replaced by *neither he could* because *nor* is used before the subject *he*. But I'm not pretty sure. Please clear my doubt.

Comment: Eliminate repeated elements which occur before *neither*: He could neither clearly identify ... nor name ..

Comment: @StoneyB: What about Subject verb agreement?

Comment: @StoneyB: Wouldn't it be possible to just remove the second "he could"?

Comment: @Stephen Exactly ... *he could* are the two repeated elements in the second clause which occur before *neither* in the first clause.

Comment: @Sudhir The only finite verb is *could*; *identify* and *name* are both infinitives.

Answer (score 2):

Using *neither* after *could* is surely possible. The *Corpus of Contemporary American English* has 200 sentences containing *could neither*.

> Freud could **neither ignore** the new culture he was thrown into **nor merge** with it seamlessly.

> He had tried to analyze the game at home and **could neither** remember **nor deduce** the development shown to him.

> It **could neither** deliver Georgia to a Republican presidential candidate **nor elect** congressmen.

Because the tags used for the question, I guess you are asking if *identify* can be used with the third singular person. It is possible because the phrase is "he could identify"; even in the case you don't repeat "he could" as in the first example I shown, "he could" is implied, and you still use *name*, not *names*.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how the *neither ... nor* construction works.

You have two clauses, each with the same beginning:

1. [**A**] NOT [**B<sub>1</sub>**]   ... [**He could**] not [**clearly identify the man who attacked him**]

   AND        and
2. [**A**] NOT [**B<sub>2</sub>**]   ... [**he could**] not [**name the weapon with which he was attacked**]

Substitute *neither* for the first NOT and *nor* for the second NOT; AND is deleted; [A] is common to both clauses, so it may be omitted on its second appearance. That leaves:

> [**A**] neither [**B<sub>1</sub>**] nor [**B<sub>2</sub>**] ... [**He could**] neither [**clearly identify the man who attacked him**] nor [**name the weapon with which he was attacked**]

You may also join two clauses with just *neither*, without *nor*; or with *nor*, without *neither*. This involves **no deletion**; *neither* or *nor* replaces *and* and you must put the finite verb of the second clause in the first position, immediately after *neither* :

> He could not clearly identify the man who attacked him; **neither could he** name the weapon with which he was attacked.
> He could not clearly identify the man who attacked him; **nor could he** name the weapon with which he was attacked.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using ***nor*** instead of ***neither*** in your final example. In fact, I think I might *prefer* it (not a particularly strong preference, admittedly).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Stupid of me to overlook that; I will amend.

Comment: Right. I think it's well-worth making the point here on ELL. We know perfectly well that both *neither* and *nor* can be used in isolation provided there's at least a ***negated*** element earlier in the text. But learners may simply assume they always have to be used as a "matched pair" - which superficially looks like a nice easy "rule" to learn, but actually isn't consistently observed by native speakers, so it should best be described as a "tendency".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, and in fact it looks like OP has mixed up the paired and the im-paired uses.

Answer (score 0):

This is an awkward sentence and I think the problem is not with the position of neither but its location next to "clearly".  Though neither is not an adverb it has an 'adverb flavor' to it that makes its position ahead of 'clearly' sound strange, just as the following sentence is strange:

> Hopefully soon he will come visit.

This sentence can be fixed by moving soon to the end -- but there is no sensible place that clearly can be moved in your sentence.  One could try

> He could neither identify his attacker clearly, nor he could name the weapon with which he was attacked.

Another alternative is to remove clearly altogether, since it carries so little meaning anyway:

> He could neither identify the man who attacked him, nor he could name the weapon with which he was attacked.