# Can you use "neither" instead of "nor" in this case?

Tags: neither-nor

Is the usage of **"nor"** instead of **"neither"** correct in these sentences? :

> *I did not believe his story, but **neither** did I believe hers*.

> *He didn't deny the reports, but **neither** did he confirm them.*

With **"nor"**:

> *I did not believe his story, but **nor** did I believe hers.*

> *He didn't deny the reports, but **nor** did he confirm them.*

*Thank you in advance!*

**Edit:** So, should I remove the **"but"** in all four sentences? :

> *I did not believe his story, **neither** did I believe hers.*

> *He didn't deny the reports, **neither** did he confirm them.*

With **"nor"**:

> *I did not believe his story, **nor** did I believe hers.*

> *He didn't deny the reports, **nor** did he confirm them.*

Comment: No. It would be correct without "but": "*I did not believe his story, nor did I believe hers.*" Unfortunately, this loses the contrast in the word "but", so the sentences do not have the exact same meaning.

Comment: All eight sentences are grammatical and idiomatic - and I see little, if any, difference in meaning among them.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be 100% grammatically correct but it sounds fine to me as a native speaker and means the same thing in all 4 sentences.

To be grammatically perfect, I agree with the other commenter that you would remove the "but".

Answer (score 1):

“Nor” does not need to be in a sentence with the word “neither.” I would suggest to just drop the "but" in all four sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps better versions of the two sentences should be

> I neither believe his story nor hers.

or even

> I believe neither of their stories.

Which I believe to be better usage of the neither / nor. For example, see [this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either_2) in the  Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: Ungrammatical.  "Neither" needs to be after the "believe" so the two parts are parallel

Comment: @Mary I'm not sure I agree. See the second answer from StoneyB to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/position-of-neither-in-the-following-sentence I would say my answer comes under the final construct **[I]** neither believe his story nor **[do I believe {omitted}]** hers